# Can not parse the type datetime

Tags: php, datetime, soap

I'm tring to call bluedart pincode master api using soap client but after passing parameters it gives error

Request parameter -

```
$params = array(
            'lastSynchDate' => '06-04-2016',
            'Profile' =>
                array(
                    'Api_type' => 'S',
                    'LicenceKey'=>$licencekey,
                    'LoginID'=>$loginid,
                    'Version'=>'1.3'
                )
        );
```

Response error -

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:

There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:lastSynchDate.
The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.DateTime.
The value '06-04-2016' cannot be parsed as the type 'DateTime'
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Although i have never used `bluedart pincode master api` but i am sure it is because the date is not in standard `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Instead of

`06-04-2016`

Try

`2016-06-04`